# reversing direction when using an enum list of directions (left to right or up to down)

Tags: c++, enums, reverse

I have an enumeration of directions declared like this:

```
enum class ShootingDirection
{
    Down,
    Up,
    Right,
    Left
};
```

I've also declared a class member of that type whose value needs to be swapped or reversed in some method. By swapped or reversed I mean Down -> Up (also vice versa) and Right -> Left (again, vice versa).

Instead of a `switch` or a bunch of if... else ifs I've used a `std::map` declared like this:

```
std::map<ShootingDirection, ShootingDirection> _invertedDirectionsMap;
```

It is filled with data like this:

```
_invertedDirectionsMap[ShootingDirection::Down] = ShootingDirection::Up;
_invertedDirectionsMap[ShootingDirection::Up] = ShootingDirection::Down;
_invertedDirectionsMap[ShootingDirection::Right] = ShootingDirection::Left;
_invertedDirectionsMap[ShootingDirection::Left] = ShootingDirection::Right;
```

Inversion of a variable whose type is ShootingDirection is then fairly simple (assuming it is initialized):

```
_direction = _invertedDirectionsMap[_direction];
```

I think that's a silly usage of a map and an unneeded overhead. Is there a smarter way?

By the way, does this question belong on Code Review or here? I'm not really familiar with the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually lay out direction enums in a circle (basically matching the way an angle would be measured from the x axis. So:

```
enum ShootingDirection { Right, Down, Left, Up };
```

matching 0 degrees, 90 degrees, 180 degrees, 270 degrees. This (to me) makes this an intuitive layout.

Then the inverted direction is simply: `(dir + 2) % 4`.  Or more fully:

```
int InvertDirection(int dir)
{
    return (dir + 2) % 4;
}
```

I like this because I find it fairly intuitive to use. A clockwise turn is `(dir + 1) % 4`, counterclockwise `(dir + 3) % 4`.

It can also be expanded to more directions easily. I use it for hexagonal directions: Inverted direction is now `(dir + 3) % 6`.

Answer (score 3):

Someone else started to imply this solution already, but this is quite fast and avoids the switch statement you said you didn't want:

```
enum ShootingDirection {
    Down = -2,
    Up = 2,
    Right = 1,
    Left = -1
};

inline ShootingDirection invert(ShootingDirection d) {
    return static_cast<ShootingDirection>(-static_cast<int>(d));
}
```

Ideally, this should compile inline to only one assembly instruction.

Comment: Nice one.  I came up with something semi similar, but this has the advantage of not introducing a new enum (it should be really fast as well.) It really depends on what the OP is after.  I think your solution or mine are ultimately the right answers.

Comment: This is quite clever, I have to say.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: use a `switch` statement instead.  It will be massively more efficient.  If that's not good enough, consider this:

```
enum class ShootingDirection
{
    Down = 1,
    Up = -1,
    Right = 2,
    Left = -2
};
```

Then you can invert by arithmetic negation (and casting to/from int of course).

Comment: It is really rarely executed and the map has only four members. I was really trying to avoid a switch, oh well.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a switch?  Anyway you can with my negation idea.

Comment: If we decide to use underlying values, we may consider `^1` instead of negation, to keep the `enum` from the question unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum class Direction {
    UP = 1,
    DOWN = 2,
    LEFT = 3,
    RIGHT = 4
};

enum class InvertedDirection {
    UP = 2,
    DOWN = 1,
    LEFT = 4,
    RIGHT = 3
};

InvertedDirection getInvertedDirection(Direction dir) {
    return static_cast<InvertedDirection>(dir);
}
```

This is the fastest you'll get.  Using static casting and then swapping out the inversion values you really can't get much faster than this.

The function is really just a helper, you can static cast wherever you like.  Either way, this will prevent the compiler from emitting any conversion code.

Comment: This is unlikely to be useful, as you'll typically want to invert the direction and store it back in a `Direction` variable, or pass it to a function expecting a `Direction`.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is there a smarter way?

Here's another approach to reversing the direction:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class ShootingDirection : unsigned char
{
   Up    = 0x00,
   Down  = 0xFF,
   Left  = 0x01,
   Right = 0xFE
};

ShootingDirection reverseDirection(ShootingDirection dir)
{
   return ShootingDirection((unsigned char)dir ^ 0xFF);
}

int main()
{
   ShootingDirection up = ShootingDirection::Up;
   ShootingDirection down = ShootingDirection::Down;
   ShootingDirection left = ShootingDirection::Left;
   ShootingDirection right = ShootingDirection::Right;

   std::cout << "Up: " << (int)up << ", Reverse: " << (int)reverseDirection(up) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Down: " << (int)down << ", Reverse: " << (int)reverseDirection(down) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Left: " << (int)left << ", Reverse: " << (int)reverseDirection(left) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Right: " << (int)right << ", Reverse: " << (int)reverseDirection(right) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Up: 0, Reverse: 255
Down: 255, Reverse: 0
Left: 1, Reverse: 254
Right: 254, Reverse: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do this without branching.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b0a1e3c58b74004

The trick is:

```
/* The direction type is 8 bits, only the first 2 are used */
/* The first 2 bits have the following meanings */
typedef unsigned char direction;
const direction down  = '\x00'; /* 00000000 */
const direction up    = '\x03'; /* 00000011 */
const direction left  = '\x01'; /* 00000001 */
const direction right = '\x02'; /* 00000010 */
/* All other values are interpreted by first zeroing out the last 6 bits */

/* Use to zero out all bits but the last two, also for XORing */
static const direction oneone = '\x03';

inline direction xorflip(const direction d)
{
    /*
     * XOR with 11
     * 00 ^ 11 = 11, down  to up
     * 01 ^ 11 = 10, left  to right
     * 10 ^ 11 = 01, right to left
     * 11 ^ 11 = 00, up    to down
     */
    return d ^ oneone;
}
```